# Use Angular Material globally with Component Library

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components, angular-library

I've created a component library in angular 6 and I would like to use Angular material components globally in my component library.

I've tried importing into app.module.ts (not exposed to library) 
I've tried altering my main.ts to include @NgModule and export a "MainModule" and this compiled fine but just doesn't seem like the right way to do this?

Am I missing something?  Wish I had some code to share but really don't even know where to start.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Yep, I already have this included what I'm tring to avoid is having to import {MatSomeModule} from '@angular/material'; in every component of my library

Comment: To use a material component (not material theme/style), you import the component module into the module that uses the component. You don't import modules into components.

Comment: Yes, I misspoke..."I already have this included what I'm tring to avoid is having to import {MatSomeModule} from '@angular/material'; in every (module) of my library."  Now with that out of the way...my question is still unanswered, Do I have to import BrowserAnimationModule into every component module I create or is there a way of importing this globally for all component modules?

Comment: You shouldn't have to import BrowserAnimationModule at all in your library, but applications using your library will. Sometimes it's easier to figure out what you need to import by trial and error - if everything works without the import then you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Angular Material components inside your library components, you should do the same as you do in a normal Angular app. That means you should import the used Angular Material modules into the library module (and/or its child feature modules):

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogModule, MatExpansionModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';

import { LibraryComponent } from './library.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatIconModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    LibraryComponent,
  ],
  declarations: [
    LibraryComponent
  ]
})
export class LibraryModule { }
```

You could also create a custom module, that holds all the used Angular Material modules and import this in other modules (like described in the second code block of this step: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-3-import-the-component-modules).

And as already described in the comments: you don't have to import `BrowserAnimationsModule`, but the project using your library must import it.

Important is, that you define `@angular/material` as `peerDependency` in your libraries `package.json` file.

Answer (score -2):

In your app.module.ts.

```
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatButtonModule
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

in app.component.html

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: app.module is not global for an Angular component library...I don't believe, becuase I tried your solution and while I have access then in app.component,html I do not have access in "my-library.component.html" under "Projects>my-library"

Comment: @Funn_Bobby is correct - app.module.ts has nothing to do with a component library other than serving as a test app. If the library is being built and published properly, each component (or feature actually, including directives and services as well as components) is its own self-contained module.